# Uploading a picture from Xamarin Forms to server WebAPI

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webapi

I have the following API method that uploads a file to the server, when called in Postman the file uploads fine.

**WebAPI**

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> UploadChallengeImage()
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Any())
    {
        foreach (var file in HttpContext.Request.Form.Files)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine("upload", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.IndexOf(".")));
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            return path;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I try to consume this in a Xamarin Forms app I get the following error -

> {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
> {
> Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2020 06:22:00 GMT
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> X-Android-Received-Millis: 1593498119607
> X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 500
> X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
> X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1593498118412
> }}

**The Xamarin Forms code**

```
async void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var stream = photo.GetStream();

        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "file",
            FileName = "test"
        };
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            content.Add(fileContent);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", MobileApp.Services.Settings.ApiToken);
            var uri = new Uri($"webserverurl/api/Challenge/UploadChallengeImage");

            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var cont = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cont))
                    {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Further diagnostics show the following in the server logs -

> StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex') at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) at App.Server.Controllers.ChallengeController.UploadChallengeImage() in  App.Server\Controllers\ChallengeController.cs:line 43

This tells me that the Xamarin is not passing any files to the API? Line 43 is foreach (var file in HttpContext.Request.Form.Files)

Comment: Seen that it is a HTTP 500 error I don't think the error is in your code. 500 means the error is on the server side.

Comment: Even though Postman works and returns 200?

Comment: Have you tried to change the content-type to `application/json` ?